# Adding ads to already finished .APK files

Tags: android, air, apk

I have several games built in Adobe Flash that were exported to .APK using Adobe AIR. I am offering some of these for free, however, I want to implement ads in them. I can not re-code them (as for some of them I do not have the original files).

Comment: do you actually own the rights to these? Why dont you have the source code

Comment: Yes I own these games. They were build in flash by several groups of people. So they all have their own way of doing things. They exported them to apks so they could be uploaded into the google play stores. As an after thought, "Why don't we have ads / free version vs. paid version".

Answer (score 0):

I am almost certain you should be able to decompile them since .apks can easilly be converted to source java files if they were created in java. Just google 'decompile .apk'. I believe its a 2 step process.

Comment: They were made in Adobe Flash.

Comment: I think you can't if you don't have source.